# How to pair rows with the same value in one column of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by

I have data in the following form :

```
set.seed(1234)
data <- data.frame(cbind(runif(40,0,10), rep(seq(1,20,1), each = 2)))
data <- data[sample(nrow(data)),]
colnames(data) <- c("obs","subject")
head(data)

    obs      subject
1.5904600      12
8.1059855      13
5.4497484       6
0.3999592      12
2.5880982      19
2.6682078       9
   ...         ...
```

Let's say that I have only two observations (column "obs") by subject (column "subject", where subjects are numbered from 1 to 20).

I would like to "group" rows by values of the "subject" column. More precisely, I would like to "order" data by subject, but conserving the order displayed above. Thus, final data would be something like this:

```
    obs      subject
1.5904600      12
0.3999592      12
8.1059855      13
2.3656473      13
5.4497484       6
7.2934746       6
```

Any ideas ? I thought of maybe identifying each row corresponding to a subject with `which`:

```
which(data$subject==x)
```

then `rbind` these rows in a loop but I am sure there is a simpler and faster way to do this, isn't it ?

Comment: Your example data is matrix, was it supposed to be a data.frame?

Comment: try something like this: `data[order(data$subject), ]`

Comment: @Bulat we will lose the original order.

Comment: `data[order(factor(data[, 'subject'], levels = unique(data[, 'subject'])), ]`

Comment: oh, ok. yes factoring by unique does it.

Answer (score 6):

Convert to factor with levels then order:

```
data$group <- factor(data$subject, levels = unique(data$subject))
data[ order(data$group), ]

#           obs subject group
# 1  1.59046003      12    12
# 4  0.39995918      12    12
# 2  8.10598552      13    13
# 30 2.18799541      13    13
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Nest the data by `obs` and unnest again. The resulting tibble will have retained the original order but `subject` will be grouped.

```
library(tidyr)
data %>% nest(obs) %>% unnest()

# A tibble: 6 × 2
#  subject       obs
#    <int>     <dbl>
#1      12 1.5904600
#2      12 0.3999592
#3      13 8.1059855
#4       6 5.4497484
#5      19 2.5880982
#6       9 2.6682078
```

Answer (score -1):

It is based on zx8754 but it does preserve the data type:

```
library(dplyr) #arrange function

group<-factor(data[,'subject'], levels=unique(data[,'subject']))
data<-cbind(data,group)
data<-arrange(as.data.frame(data),group)
data<-as.matrix(data[,-3])
```

Answer (score -3):

`dplyr` is a great package with various useful verbs, one of which is `arrange(variable)`, which does what you want here, and more elegantly (result is generally also a data.frame, so you don't need to `cbind`):

```
require(dplyr)
as.data.frame(data) %>% arrange(subject)
# or, if you want reverse order:
as.data.frame(data) %>% arrange(-subject)
```

(For that matter, `data.table` is great too. In fact, you can get them both merged in `dtplyr` package)

Comment: This is not what OP wants, check output.

Comment: Oh you mean order by 'subject', then by original ordering of 'obs'. Will fix